# create ES6 class definition at runtime and add to 'factory' list to be used

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

Below is my current implementation, compiled using Webpack.

```
// ** ModelTypeA.js ** //
export class ModelTypeA {
  constructor() {
  }
  //etc, class definition
}


// ** ModelFactory.js ** //
export { ModelTypeA } from './ModelTypeA';
export { ModelTypeB } from './ModelTypeB';


// ** Main.js  ** //
import * as ModelFactory from './ModelFactory.js'

let modelName = "ModelTypeA"; //can be changed to "ModelTypeB"
let myModel = new ModelFactory[modelName];
```

Is there a way to create another class, for example ModelTypeC.js with its definition during runtime (let's say I have a text editor on the webpage to write and save), append it to ModelFactory.js, and use it in Main.js?

Comment: Why you want to create and load file? Why not just use `eval`?

Comment: Swapping out modules during runtime would need to be supported by your specific module loader. Webpack definitely doesn't.

Comment: @Arnial : the idea is to be able to maintain all the modelTypes (should be able to have CRUD operation on the later part)

Comment: @Bergi : what about commonJS? Found the sample code below. Haven't tested though..

`// foo.js
const foo = {}
module.exports = foo
somethingAsync().then(result => foo[result.key] = result.value)

// bar.js
const {foobar} = require('./foo')`

Comment: @cristie09: The format (commonjs, es6, amd, etc) is not important, the *loader* needs to support it. It'll need to override the old with the new module and re-run all that depend on it.

Comment: @Bergi ok i think i understand what you mean, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's set aside the fact that allowing users to write JS code in a text editor on your site is often a Bad Idea.

You won't be able to do what you describe because ES6 modules don't allow runtime changes to `import`/`export` statements. [This article](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/misunderstanding-es6-modules-upgrading-babel-tears-and-a-solution-ad2d5ab93ce0) has a decent overview, key quote:

> Here’s the basic idea: ES6 modules are supposed to be statically analyzable (runtime cannot change the exports/imports) so it can’t be dynamic.

What you could do in this scenario is to register the classes with the factory in some way that doesn't involve `import`/`export`:

```
class ModelFactory {
    constructor() {
        this._classes = {}
    }
    register(key, cls) {
        this._classes[key] = cls
    }
    create(key, ...args) {
        return new this._classes[key](...args);
    }
}

// Export a singleton
export default new ModelFactory();

// Register in some other file
import { ModelTypeA } from './ModelTypeA';
import { ModelTypeB } from './ModelTypeB';
import ModelFactory from './ModelFactory';

ModelFactory.register('ModelTypeA', ModelTypeA);
ModelFactory.register('ModelTypeB', ModelTypeB);
```

Now you could bring in some user-authored class and register that too:

```
const className = userProvidedData.className;
// Again, don't really do this, it's usually a Bad Idea
const cls = eval(userProvidedData.source);
ModelFactory.register(className, cls);
```

Comment: You should not uses `class`es for singletons. Export an object literal if you really must, or export the class and instantiate it where you need it.

Comment: @Bergi - Any rationale? Classes enjoy nice syntax, and you can export the class definition separately for testing (testing singletons is incredibly annoying). Instantiating in the module ensures that all importers get the shared singleton, without having to pass it around everywhere.

Comment: Objects enjoy exactly the same nice syntax (the only difference are commas), but don't have any overhead of prototypes. If you want to export the class it's fine to export a singleton alongside, but you would actually have to export the class (which you didn't in your answer). And even then, I'd recommend to use explicit naming (`export const singleton = new ModelFactory`, `import {singleton as ModelFactory} from …`) instead of the default export to make it clear that everyone is dealing with global state.

Comment: If all you're exporting is a singleton class or an object, why even bother with the object when you can export the functions themselves as named exports.

Comment: @nrabinowitz tried implementing it and it works, thanks! It kinda serve the purpose for now despite the the fact that it usually is a bad idea.. Until further requirements.. then will just be using this first.

Comment: @loganfsmyth In this case, the functions would need to share state (the registry). There are reasonable arguments for that, but personally I like to only export stateless functions to reduce confusion.

Comment: @Bergi - Curious whether the prototype is really overhead - I was under the impression that at least some JS runtimes optimized "true" classes better than object literals. The point about explicit singleton export is reasonable.

Comment: @nrabinowitz: Maybe the optimisation happens earlier, but I don't think it'll be overall better.

Answer (score -2):

Defining a class during runtime is (most of the time) a bad idea.
It's very prone to RunTimeException..

If those Model classes have something in commons, it's better to have a generic class and change the behaviour of the instance based on the properties it has.

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is prone to runtime exceptions :-)

Comment: First of all, the source is untested, and if there are too many classes defined, It will be very hard to maintain the code. If the classes are too big or are tightly coupled,  it will be a problem... not to mention that a text editor is used to define the class...